# Spotify Implicit Grant Flow- Missing required parameter: client_id

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, react-native, spotify

I'm facing an issue that I don't understand! 
I am developing a react-native (js) app which try to access Spotify api using the Implicit Grant Flow.

Here is my method to get the access token:

```
async function getTokenFromAPI() {
    try {
        var params = {
            client_id: '<client_id>',
            response_type: 'token',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8888/callback'
        };

        var esc = encodeURIComponent;
        var query = Object.keys(params)
            .map(k => `${esc(k)}=${esc(params[k])}`)
            .join('&');

        fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize', query).then(function (response) {
            console.log('response, ' + JSON.stringify(response));
            return response;
        })
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

but It answers that: 
`Missing required parameter: client_id`

I also used Postman to check if my request is good and I get the same response...

Is there something wrong? On their [doc](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) they tell that it is a GET method with only 3 parameters..

Thank you in advance for any workaround!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving query parameters as options to `fetch` rather than adding it to the url.

change this

```
fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize', query).then(function () { ... })
```

to this

```
fetch(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize${query}`).then(function () { ... })
```